# Use multiple node versions with iisnode

Tags: node.js, iis, iisnode

I am using iisnode.  On the same server I need to run different versions of node for different websites.  I have nvm installed on the server.  How do I tell iisnode which version of node I want to start for each site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a nodeProcessCommandLine entry to web.config that points to the specific node.exe file you want to use:

```
<configuration>
    ...
    <system.webServer>
        ...
        <iisnode  nodeProcessCommandLine="C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v6.9.2\node.exe"  />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```